# SAPUI5 Two-way binding: How do I clear/refresh the binding every time I navigate to the app?

Tags: odata, sapui5

I have an issue with two-way binding when returning to a freestyle SAPUI5 app.

Say for example...

I navigate to App 1. The loads the OData fine, via two-way binding.

I then navigate away from App 1 to App 2. This also loads the OData for App 2 fine.

Now when I navigate back to App 1, The OData isn't loaded again, with the binding remaining from the first time into App 1.

I then navigate to App 2, same issue, the OData isn't reloaded, and the binding from the first entry into App 2 remains.

Ideally, I would like the binding cleared every time I enter an app, be it the 1st time in (initialization) or when navigating to it.

Is this possible to do with manifest properties? (much preferable) Or will a refresh need to be triggered in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

We usually use JSON Models instead of OData Models, but whenever we run into this kind of problem, we use `onBeforeRendering` or `onAfterRendering` (depends on the situation) methods in the controller.

Thinking of `sap.m.Router` with routes configured in the `manifest.json` I don't see a configurable solution.

You could try to implement the loading via one of `sap.m.routing.Router`'s events (e.g. `routeMatched`), but the last time I tried to accomplish a similar requirement like yours, I ended up in the controller again, because the `routeMatched` event fires before the UI elements are present when calling the view for the first time.

Comment: Sorry, I have zero knowledge in ASP.Net